# Can check-in agents see whether I selected the seat myself or was automatically assigned by the system?

Tags: air-travel, check-in, seating

I wonder whether check-in agents see whether I selected the seat myself or was automatically assigned by the system.

Motivation: I sometimes forget whether I selected the seat myself, and would like to check that with the check-in agent. If I selected the seat myself no need to change, if the system selected it then I may discuss the possibility of changing it (since in some cases, seat selection isn't available at the time if the booking).

Comment: Why worry, if you like the seat use it, if not ask for a change, whether you selected it or not. (Even when you select it you may not get the best seat available, due to others changing seats later.)

Comment: @Willeke I don't know whether I like it without looking at a seat map

Comment: That remains the same whether you chose it or it was selected by a machine.

Comment: @Willeke if I chose it, I know it's good enough. Therefore it's not the same.

Comment: "if the system selected it then I may discuss the possibility of changing it", both airlines and the fellow passengers in the line behind you want a quick check-in so even if they know they don't want to discuss it with you

Comment: @Anders you're welcome to post it an answer. I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt sadly I just have the answer to your problem, not to your question :-(

Answer (score 2):

1. Check in online
2. Select the seat that you want on the seat map that's conveniently in front of you
3. If in doubt look it up on seatguru.com
4. Don't bother the check-in agent and hold up everyone in line with something that can be easier and better done online. Some airlines actually charge extra for physical check-in

Comment: Thanks, check in online is sometimes not possible though, eg in some international flights from the US as a US lawful permanent resident (I believe because the airline staff wants to see the green card).

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt, so you check in online when you can, so you know you have selected your seat then. And then you know that when you have to check in at the airport you have not (yet) selected your seat. (Or take notes and keep them handy and check before you reach the counter.)

Comment: @Willeke that doesn't work because seat reservation can sometimes be made when purchasing the flight ticket.

Comment: What is so difficult about 'keep notes and have them handy when checking in'? Besides, the range of seats available at checking in might be quite different from those when buying, so double checking is always worth it.

Comment: @Willeke that's inconvenient. What is so difficult about asking the check-in agent?

Comment: You can always ask the agent (when you check in in person) to see if better seats are available, No need to ask whether you already have chosen a seat, as your favorite may now be available.

Comment: @Willeke better seat is subjective, it'll take a of time to mention my preferences / for the agent to understand, and they may misunderstand it. I prefer to rely on myself looking at the plane seat plan.